# Azure DevOps (VSTS) self-hosted Agent update URL

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to whitelist URLs for access required by Azure DevOps (VSTS Agent).

However, when trying to do a self-update, I receive the following error (file is /vsts-agent/_diag/Agent_20181127-213126-utc.log):

> [2018-11-27 21:37:49Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: An error occurred: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
>   [2018-11-27 21:37:49Z ERR  AgentProcess] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishGetStreamAsync(Task`1 getTask)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.SelfUpdater.DownloadLatestAgent(CancellationToken token)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.SelfUpdater.SelfUpdate(AgentRefreshMessage updateMessage, IJobDispatcher jobDispatcher, Boolean restartInteractiveAgent, CancellationToken token)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.RunAsync(AgentSettings settings)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.RunAsync(AgentSettings settings)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.RunAsync(AgentSettings settings)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.ExecuteCommand(CommandSettings command)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Program.MainAsync(IHostContext context, String[] args)

However, there is no URL listed to whitelist!

The closest I found was:

- [Configuring Proxy with VSTS Agents](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/agents/proxy.md)
- [Whitelisted URLs for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/faq-network-connections?view=vsts)

Note the agent is configured successfully and can successfully run builds. It is just every time an update comes around, it fails and won't run builds until it is removed/reconfigured (not an option - this is an agent, not interactive).

Comment: As a last resort, you could install the Hosted Agent on an unrestricted server and monitor the traffic during the update.

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline agent is open source.  The code can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent).

Glancing through the trace, I'd guess it is throwing the error here:

```
using (Stream result = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(_targetPackage.DownloadUrl))
```

Looking through the [assets.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/3e0e6dd0111fa53e72e42e4cf14f94ac379cba5a/assets.json) specifying the DownloadUrl, I'd guess this is the URL you will want:

```
https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/<AGENT_VERSION>/vsts-agent-win-x64-<AGENT_VERSION>.zip
```